# Azure Web Apps Deployment options Dropbox can not select folder and change account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I try to setup a azure web apps  to use Dropbox as the source, BUT

1,  I can not choose the folder, it force me to create a new folder, when I click the choose folder menu, it only list one which is the name of this new web apps, doesn't showing the other existing folders in my dropbox. But I have some existing folders under the dropbox, which some of them are using by my other web apps.

2 then I try to change the account, go the authorization menu, when I click the Change Account button, it open a new window with http 400 error, with following information:

https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=kiqukvsyjo7cymc&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.azure.com%2FTokenAuthorize&response_type=code&state=09f09ec2-13d0-4613-97c2-19abdab1957d

Error (400)
It seems the app you were using submitted a bad request. If you would like to report this error to the app's developer, include the information below.

More details for developers

Invalid redirect_uri: "https://portal.azure.com/TokenAuthorize": It must exactly match one of the redirect URIs you've pre-configured for your app (including the path).
.
This used to work very smoothly but seems not working anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: There seems to be an issue indeed. We will investigate and get back to you.

Comment: great, thanks for prompt response

Comment: Change account is now fixed, but we're still looking at the issue with the list of folders.

Comment: yes, change account fixed, the folder list still not, just confirmed.

Comment: Folder issue is understood. We're working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue on the App Service side, caused by the switch over to the v2 Dropbox API. Both issues are now resolved, so you should be able to change the account as well as pick an existing folder.